# How to convert Null to String with Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, entity

I'm trying to use reflection within a linq query to change a Decimal Null value to a string value.  My code produce this error;

"Object of type System.String cannot be converted to type System.Nullable System.Decimal"

Thanks for your help.

```
public class ReportData
    {

        public IEnumerable<SASF> GetLongReportData(string commSubGp)
        {

            var context = new Entities();
            string myDate = "2014-03-18";
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);

            var result = new List<SASF>();

            if (commSubGp == "F00")
            {               


                result = (from a in context.SASF
                                     where a.RDate == date &&
                                     a.COMM_SGP.CompareTo("F00") <= 0
                                     orderby a.Conmkt, a.MKTTITL descending
                                     select a).ToList();

                //Here I'm trying to use reflection to loop through the object and set any value that's null to string value
                result.ForEach(reflect =>
                {
                    reflect.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(p =>
                    {
                        var checkValue = p.GetValue(reflect, null);
                        if (checkValue == null)
                        {
                            p.SetValue(reflect, "non-reportable", null);
                        }

                    });
                });

                return result.ToList();
             }

             return results;

           }

      }
```

Comment: You mention you are trying to change a decimal to a string value but the error message states you are trying to convert a string to a decimal.

Comment: The SQL database table has all decimal data types except for the id column and the date time column.

Comment: If the type is already a decimal you will not be able to store a string in the property. You need to create a new object that has properties as strings and project the data into the new object.

Comment: @Xpanse, if I understand you correctly.  I need to create a new object that has string properties, map it through entity, then write a query using the new created object and return that object "ToList()"?

Comment: I am talking general C# here, not EF as I don't know enough about EF to say whether or not this would work. I am just preparing an a real answer which should all you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since your property type is Decimal? the string "non-reportable" can not be converted to Decimal and the value fails to set. You could set it to zero however:

```
p.SetValue(reflect, Decimal.Zero, null)
```

Or any decimal value for that matter.

```
p.SetValue(reflect, Decimal.MinValue, null)
p.SetValue(reflect, Decimal.MaxValue, null)
```

Not knowing what the data is to be used for in the end I have no idea whether this would be appropriate or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection to do this probably isn't the best solution as it is quite an expensive process. Utilising the method below allows you to be specific and output the data in a way you see fit (although you could do this on the DB side too).

Without knowing the structure of the SASF class I have just created a pseudo class.

This of course requires you to specifically map each field to your stringified class. You might be able to use some tool like AutoMapper (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to do this for you.

```
public class ReportData
{
    public IEnumerable<SASFStringified> GetLongReportData(string commSubGp)
    {

        var context = new Entities();
        string myDate = "2014-03-18";
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);

        var result = new List<SASF>();

        if (commSubGp == "F00")
        {


            result = (from a in context.SASF
                      where a.RDate == date &&
                      a.COMM_SGP.CompareTo("F00") <= 0
                      orderby a.Conmkt, a.MKTTITL descending
                      select a).ToList();

            var stringifiedResult = new List<SASFStringified>();
            foreach (var sasf in result)
            {
                stringifiedResult.Add(new SASFStringified
                {
                    ID = sasf.ID,
                    Field1 = sasf.Field1.HasValue ? sasf.Field1.Value.ToString() : "non-reportable",
                    Field2 = sasf.Field2.HasValue ? sasf.Field2.Value.ToString() : "non-reportable",
                    DateField = sasf.DateField.ToShortDateString()
                });
            }

            return stringifiedResult;
        }

        return results;

    }
}

public class SASF
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal? Field1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Field2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateField { get; set; }
}

public class SASFStringified
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string DateField { get; set; }
}
```